# Python match string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Couldn't get how `re.match(patern, string)` works. I need to check if string mathes regular expresion. For example - string should match at least 9 at most 10 (not more!) alpha-numeric symbols:

```
pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,10}'
string_not_match = 'jaguargames.infinity'
string_match = 'kj12345678'
bool(re.match(pattern, string_not_match))  # True but why???!!!!
bool(re.match(pattern, string_match))  # True as expected
```

I tried

```
bool(re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,10}').match(string_not_match))
```

but it't just a different syntax and result is still True. It works weird - it matches 10 symbols of the string and returns True.

How I get **False** to `string_not_match` and **True** to `string_match` for pattern `'[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,10}'` ?

UPD: The pattern to match whole string should be `'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,10}$'`. Thanks to @MarkTolonen and @EftalGezer.

Comment: Drop the `bool` coercion and look at the match and you'll see why.  `match` must start at the beginning of the string, but with your pattern it doesn't have to match the *whole* string.

Comment: Because the first one matches `jaguargame`. https://regex101.com/r/hJVXrf/1
What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @EftalGezer I'm trying to get True to non-case-sensitive alphanumeric string that contains at least 9 at most 10 (not more) symbols. Otherwise False.

Comment: @Kereell Your regular expression should be `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,10}$`. `^` indicates the beginning of the line and `$` indicates the end of the line. https://regex101.com/r/6HZHuQ/1

Comment: @EftalGezer thanks. Didn't notice the problem in pattern - focused on re.match.